# How to calculate Work Factor in Computer Security?

Tags: security, computer-science, calculation, brute-force

can anyone shed some light on the question below?

**A bank system relies on a secret code of 4 digits. Calculate on the work
factor for breaking the code using brute force.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do: 4 digits give you a space of 10000 possibilities. Statistically you will guess the code in half of the tries, so about 5000.